# Node js await is not working while connecting to postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, async-await, connection, es6-promise

I have created a saperate js file in node js and I am trying to connect to postgres sql using below code but it never worked. always promise is pending. code is not waiting at this line (await client.connect()). I Could not understand what the issue is. can any one please help me on this.

```
const pg = require('pg');
async function PostgresConnection(query,config) {
    const client = new pg.Client(config);
    await client.connect(); //not waiting for the connection to succeed and returning to caller and exit
    const pgData = await client.query(query);
    await client.end();
    return pgData;
}
async function uploadDataToPostgres(config) {
   var query="select * from firm_data";
   await PostgresConnection(query, config); 
}
 module.exports = {
  uploadDataToPostgres
}
```

I am trying to call above method from other page

```
function ProcessData()
{
  var result = uploadDataToPostgres(config);
}
```

Comment: One error I see is that your function PostgresConnection is missing config parameter.

Comment: What is your nodejs and pg version.

Comment: How did you determine that connect is not waited? Also uploadDataToPostgres doesn't return a result, it returns a promise of undefined,

Comment: Where is your config? You are not sending config on here

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke an async function from outside an async function, you need to treat it as a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Change your invoker function to look like this:

```js
function ProcessData() {
    uploadDataToPostgres(config)
        .then(function success(result) {
            /* do something useful with your result */
            console.log(result)
        })
        .catch(function error(err) {
            console.error('uploadDataToPostgres failure', err)
        })
}
```

Your code, `var result = uploadDataToPostgres(config)`, stashes a Promise object in `result`. But the code behind the promise (the code in your async function) doesn't run until you invoke `.then()` or `.else()` on it.

It's a bit confusing until you completely grasp the similarity between async functions and Promises: async functions are Promise functions with nice syntax.

It's possible your `uploadDataToPostgres()` function throws an error (failure to connect to the db?) and the `.catch()` will catch that.